# Create custom warning messages in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2

I'm using the `If Expression Is` logical in ModelBuilder to split my process into two different branches based on user inputs.

Everything works as expected, but I always get a warning at the end due to the one of the preconditions being false.

This model builder is going to be passed to another person to assist with some repetitive processes. IMO this yellow warning can look a bit *scary*, especially for someone not super familiar with how model builder works. I was hoping I can either change this warning to my own message or suppress it (but only suppress this specific warning).

[image]

Comment: You will not be able to suppress it or change the message. If you want custom messages you need to convert your model into a python script and create your own messages.